# android 2.3.3 apps menu list icons

Tags: android, list, menu

The application list in 2.3.3 looks like this where is the code of that?

http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/4e0cb6e0cadcbbc53f020000-590/the-galaxy-s-ii-runs-android-version-233-not-a-huge-fan-of-the-touchwiz-skin-though.jpg

Answer (score 1):

That is the TouchWiz UI, which is a proprietary Samsung interface, and AFAIK it is not open source, so you will not be able to find the source code online.

On the other hand, you could try looking into the open source launchers available, and their themes. A good one to start with would be [ADW](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/).